# Having issues Deserialising a JSON model in controller

Tags: c#, javascript, json

I have the following C# Models but they do not get the Id or AssigneeId populated from the JSON any help please?:

```
public class AssignModel
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public bool Clear { get; set; }
    public string AssigneeId { get; set; }
}

public class MassAssignModel
{
    [Required]
    public List<AssignModel> Tickets { get; set; }
} 


public ActionResult MassAssign(MassAssignModel model)
{
    //DO stuff here
}
```

I am try to have these populated by deserialising JSON but it never get the values. Here is my javascript, the first method call is massAssign():

```
function massAssign() {
    assignTicketsTo(getSelectedTicketsIds());
}

function getSelectedTicketsIds() {
    var tickets;
    var selected = $('.selected-ticket:checked');
    tickets = selected.map(function () {
    return { Id: this.value, AssigneeId: "COMPONENTS\ASTANNARD", Clear:false };
    }).get();

    return tickets;
}

function assignTicketsTo(selectedTicketsIds) {

    var postdata = JSON.stringify({
        Tickets: [selectedTicketsIds]
    });

    $.ajax({
    url: Helper.Util.action({ controller: "Ticket", action: "MassAssign" }),
    dataType: 'json',
    data: postdata,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#load_tickets").hide();
        Helper.alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send JSON to an MVC controller you need to set the `contentType` to `'application/json'` in your `$.ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: Helper.Util.action({ controller: "Ticket", action: "MassAssign" }),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: postdata,
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $("#load_tickets").hide();
        Helper.alert(errorThrown);
    }
```

[dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is for

> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

You have one additional problem with your code, when you are creating the `postdata` the `selectedTicketsIds` variable already contains an array so you don't need to wrap it again with `[selectedTicketsIds]`.

So change your `postdata` to:

```
var postdata = JSON.stringify({
        Tickets: selectedTicketsIds
});
```

Comment: Hi I made the change to content type but it make no difference, I guess that was wrong anyway but does not correct my issue

Comment: Please log out the `postdata` before the `$.ajax` and include it in your post.

Comment: Maybe I see now... your `selectedTicketsIds` is already an array so you don't need to wrap it again with `[selectedTicketsIds]`. Please try it with `var postdata = JSON.stringify({
        Tickets: selectedTicketsIds
    });` together with the `contentType: 'application/json'`